# How to auto-unlock gnome-keyring upon (auto-)login?

Tags: linux-mint, login, gnome-keyring, seahorse

I am on Linux Mint 17.3 and have the auto-login enabled. I have my SSH key in `gnome-keyring`.

I would like the keyring not to ask me for my password upon login. I am aware the auto-login itself may seem to pose a security risk, but this question is not about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I ended up disabling the auto-login.
2. Now, log out and log in again.
3. The next time you try to connect to SSH there will likely be a checkbox to automatically unlock this key, which I checked and proceeded with login.
4. After reboot, you have increased security by disabling the auto-login and it should not ask for a password for the keyring anymore.